# Получение кода ответа при запросе PHP

Tags: php

Необходимо послать GET/POST запрос и получить код ответа, полученное содержание роли не играет. Возможно ли такое реализовать? Желательно без curl.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь функцией `file_get_contents()` ( http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php )

Comment: "код ответа" - это http status code? Тогда к `file_get_contents` надо добавить и [`$http_response_header `](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php). Не уверен (не проверял), но может быть сработает и [`get_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php), если `stream_context` указать соответствующий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаем только заголовки и проверяем код ответа:

```
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
$headers = @get_headers($url);
if (!empty($headers[0])) {
    preg_match('/\d{3}/', $headers[0], $matches);
    echo $matches[0] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Хотя особой разницы с получением полного ответа нет, на сервер придёт обычный HTTP/1.0 запрос.

Результаты get_headers:

```
$headers = get_headers($url, 0);
array(14) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  [1]=>
  string(35) "Date: Fri, 25 Mar 2016 08:39:49 GMT"
  [2]=>
  string(38) "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
  ...


$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
array(13) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  ["Date"]=>
  string(29) "Fri, 25 Mar 2016 08:40:48 GMT"
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(24) "text/html; charset=utf-8"
  ...
```

Для отправки POST запросов можно curl использовать и получать из ответа http-status. К тому же при POST обычно и данные посылают.

Как заметил @BOPOH, через get_headres и доп. заголовки можно передавать, в том числе установить метод HEAD или POST. Пример с методом POST:

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Accept-language: en\r\n",
        )
    )
);
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
$headers = get_headers($url);
```

stackoveflow ругнулся что string(28) "HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required" должны быть POST данные, на некоторых ресурсах с пустыми POST-даннымии отвечает 200.

Comment: не уверен, что `get_headers()` нормально отрабатывает с post-запросом. Вы бы проверили и если сработает - написали бы это в ответе с примером кода

Comment: @BOPOH POST-запросы не получится, `get_headers` только для GET-запросов..

Comment: так там же можно context передавать - он тоже не помогает? мне просто самому проверять лень ))) своих дел по горло

Comment: Глянул, у [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-headers.php) есть второй необязательный параметр $format. Если он имеет ненулевое значение, то заголовки ещё по ключам разбиваются. Т.е. если было в массиве 1 =>  "Server: nginx/1.6.2", то становится  'Server' => 'nginx/1.6.2'. А метод все равно GET )

Comment: вы посмотрите там *Пример #2 Пример использования запроса HEAD в функцииget_headers()* - там написано что по умолчанию используется get, но можно и head. Но ведь можно через stream_context_set_default и post задать, только сработает ли это - не знаю, может быть проигнорирует и get'ом отправит (я про это говорю)

Comment: @BOPOH да, вы правы! не знал) Можно и метод нужный установить..

Comment: так установить-то можно, а вот сработает ли это? будет ли это post-запрос? время будет - посмотрю

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37507/discussion-between-jekaby-and-bopoh).

Answer (score 1):

Через `file_get_contents`

```
function getStatusCode($url, $method) {
    file_get_contents($url, null, stream_context_create(['http' => ['method' => $method]]));
    return $http_response_header[0];
}


// "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
var_dump(
    getStatusCode('https://habrahabr.ru', 'GET')
);
// "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
var_dump(
    getStatusCode('https://habrahabr.ru', 'POST')
);
// "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"
var_dump(
    getStatusCode('https://ya.ru', 'POST')
);
```